# how can i convert binary string to integer in android studio?

Tags: android

I'm a self android learner. Code given below shows errors. Please help me to correct the errors. Here I want to convert a binary string stored in `s` to corresponding integer value.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String s = "110";
    int num = Integer.parseInt(s);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText(num);
    setContentView(textView);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

XML Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context="com.example.addition.AdditionActivity" >

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my logcat:

```
03-29 16:39:42.608 5722-5722/com.example.user.rec E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.rec/com.example.user.rec.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x6
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x6
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:230)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3776)
        at com.example.user.rec.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
03-29 16:39:52.567 5722-5722/com.example.user.rec I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5722 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int num = Integer.parseInt("110", 2);
```

where `2` is your base (or radix). Here is a
[link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to the official documentation.

Comment: It also shows me error. Plz go through entire code and help me

Comment: It also shows me error "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.rec/com.example.user.rec.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x6".plz tell me to how to rectify this

Comment: can you update your post with the logcat output and AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @harisg you need to convert `num` to string before passing it to setText -> `textView.setText(String.valueOf(num));`